# VS2015RTM Cordova Tools configuration for ios remote build agent no longer valid - taco-remote package not found

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

Updated VS2015RC to RTM - Cordova Tools configuration for ios remote build agent is no longer valid. VS2015RTM cannot find taco-remote package installed on the remote mac (but VS2015RC could).

This is how it looks from the build remote agent command prompt (note 404 response not found):

```
Remote build server listening on [http] port 3000
ios-sim is installed on path at: /Users/admin/node-v0.12.4-darwin-x64/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/node_modules/ios-sim/build/release/ios-sim

GET /modules/taco-remote 404 12ms
```

npm taco-remote --version outputs 2.10.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054(v=vs.140).aspx) - 
Visual Studio 2015 has an updated remote agent called remotebuild. vs-mda-remote, the previous agent, is for use with Visual Studio 2015 RC and earlier versions.

Following instructions from link above, I am now getting
GET /modules/taco-remote 200 21.968 ms (note 200 response ok), as expected

Comment: Spent a few hours on this one. Microsoft have renamed he remote agent a few times. The latest one is now remotebuild which you can install by doing "sudo npm install -g remotebuild". Reference doc is here https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#first-install-a-few-things-onto-your-mac