# VS2015 Cordova Tools configuration for ios remote build agent not valid - taco-remote package not found

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I followed the steps to set up a remote build at:https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#stack

I am able to pair from visual studio but when I try to set ios configuration from Tools for apache cordova I receive the following error response on the apple machine:

---

```
Last login: Mon Apr 11 11:31:07 on ttys000
Johns-Mac-mini:~ johnbowyer$ vcremote --secure false
vcremote
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
1.0.8

VC build library initialized.
Remote build server listening on [http] port 3030
GET /modules/taco-remote 404 7ms
GET /modules/taco-remote 404 2ms
GET /modules/taco-remote 404 0ms
```

From Visual Studio I receive the error:  Unable to connect to remote IOS Build server.   Underlying exceptions.  The remote server returned an error:  (404) Not Found.

- It appears that this person had a similar problem but I am not clear
  what they did as a fix that I am not doing since I am using vcremote:
  [VS2015RTM Cordova Tools configuration for ios remote build agent no longer valid - taco-remote package not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569621/vs2015rtm-cordova-tools-configuration-for-ios-remote-build-agent-no-longer-valid)
- It appears that this person had a similar problem but it seems they
  may have switch to a different mac which I don't have the option to
  do:
  [Visual Studio Cordova, building iOS package via remote agent issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418953/visual-studio-cordova-building-ios-package-via-remote-agent-issues)

The results of npm taco-remote are

```
Last login: Mon Apr 11 11:35:50 on ttys002
Johns-Mac-mini:~ johnbowyer$ npm taco-remote --version
3.8.6
```

Answer (score 3):

In your initial post you were using the `vcremote` package to launch the remote build, which is only for use with Visual C++ projects. It looks like you fixed it by using the `remotebuild` package (`npm install -g remotebuild`), which is the one you want to use for Cordova projects. It may be a bit confusing since both tools use some shared source behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but running the following command appeared to resolve this issue:

```
johnbowyer$ remotebuild -test
```

Comment: This actually helped me because even though I had configured not to use secure mode, when I ran 'remotebuild -test' I saw that somehow my remotebuild was configured with secure mode.. So I just switched my configuration on VS studio to secure mode and defined the Security PIN which was shown after running the command.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

When I ran `remotebuild -test`, it complained that no server modules were selected, and went on to default configuration "modules" to taco-remote